# How could i push a commit to heroku that has already been pushed to git from local repo?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, push

I encounter this weird situation...

I have a commit pushed to github...

then the commit disappears from git status...

how can I commit that same file to heroku?

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First add the heroku remote to your local git.

```
git remote add <your heroku git url>
```

replace `<your heroku git url>` with your actual heroku git url, you can find it from settings tab of on your heroku dashboard, it looks something like this: `https://git.heroku.com/app-name.git`

once heroku remote is added, you can simply push the latest commit by:

```
git push heroku master
```

replace `master` with whatever branch you want to push, normally it is `master`

Comment: thanks, will this push to Github and to Heroku at the same time?

Comment: No this will only push to heroku.. if you want to push to github too, you can run 'git push origin master' separately